# How to use sub_filter for serving static files?

Tags: nginx

I need to serve static html-files with content replace.

I try:

```
server {
   root /var/www/test;
   location / {
        gzip off;
        sub_filter test test1;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work :( content is not modified.

Content type: text/html

nginx -V:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.9.4
built by gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-cc-opt=-Wno-error --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module
```

curl http://example.com/test.html -I:

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.4
Date: Sat, 12 Sep 2015 21:43:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 5
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Sep 2015 17:27:30 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "55f30f02-5"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a description of a problem. Please be more detailed.

Comment: content is not modified

Comment: Please add that information to the question by editing.

Comment: Show request, response and what you expected. Also check if nginx has sub_filter enabled. (see `nginx -V`)

Comment: request is standard curl -I, response is unchanged. I've attached headers to question.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

So while your question doesn't show the actual content that is unchanged, leading to doubt in the issue, I was having this same problem.

I came across [this thread](http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/replace-string-in-content-td7582188.html) where the submitter eventually claimed that changing the port of his server caused it to begin working.  I found this silly myself, but it worked for me.

It is possible this simply busted a cached response in my browser, so you might also simply try clearing your cache if your agent caches responses (you show curl, so that's probably n/a).  Also, try specifying the mime type with `sub_filter_type`, although given your response seems to be `text/html`, I doubt that is the issue as it is the [stated default](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter_types).